# git checkout -b newbranch lost changes on current branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch

So basically, here's what happened with me:

1. I was working on a branch, let's call it 'dev'
2. I didn't yet stage or commit my changes. However, I needed to test something quick for someone in a new branch.
3. So I executed git checkout -b testbranch dev on the command line
4. This created a branch called 'testbranch' off of 'dev' and checked out that branch
5. However, all the files I had modified in my 'dev' branch (which I didn't stash, stage, and commit prior to executing point 3) got listed in the terminal with a M next to them to indicate modified.
6. I worked on the testbranch and once the work was complete, staged and committed my changes and switched back to 'dev' branch.
7. Unfortunately, it looks like that all the changes I had made in the dev branch prior to creating/switching the testbranch got lost when I looked at the project in xcode.

So my question is: Is there any way for me to recover the files? Note that my terminal session is still running and I will keep it running until I either get a solution to recover my changes or I find out that those changes are lost forever. HELP!!!!

Thanks,

-Vivek Kinra

Comment: The changes were not lost. They flowed right on into your `testbranch` (as you said in step 5) and are still there (you committed them in step 6). You don't see them in the `dev` commit because that's not where they got committed; these are changes you made _after_ the `dev` commit. But switch back again to the `testbranch` commit and there they are.

Comment: You'll notice that I refer to a branch as a commit. That is all a branch is: it is a name pointing to a commit. It really helps to keep that in mind when you visualize what's going on.

Comment: Matt, thanks a lot! I was able to recover a day's worth of work!

Comment: :) But in general I hope you learned a lesson: always stash or commit before leaving one branch for another. You don't actually have to (unless a conflict would ensue, in which case git will stop you), but it sure keeps things simpler.

Comment: By the way, the reason it was so easy to do what you did is that it is perfectly reasonable to write some new code and then say to yourself, You know this really ought to be off in a branch of its own. And that is exactly what you _did_ do. :)

Comment: Thanks Matt, note that if you want to update your comment and put it in an answer, I will accept it!

Comment: No problem, you can accept mu's answer if you like. I was just happy I was able to reassure you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your changes are not lost.

The first time they were there on the new `testbranch` after step 3, it was because the changes weren't committed to branch `dev`.

Next, when you committed those to the `testbranch`, the commit got associated with `testbranch`, and thus won't be available on `dev` branch before you explicitly tell `git` to do so.

In this case, it seems to me that you are fine with all the code in `testbranch` to be brought into `dev` branch, so you can do a simple `merge`.

```
git checkout dev
git merge testbranch
```

This will bring all your changes to `dev` branch.

Comment: Adding to this answer, you can get only the specific commits if required - assuming you have done additional changes in testbranch, which you dont want in your base branch. Try cherrypick specific commit if you dont want to make both branches look same with the code.

Comment: @VinayVeluri I don't think we need to cherry pick commits in this case, OP checked out a branch from `dev`, and made commits there alone, all of which he needs, so a merge should suffice.

Comment: True.! I wanted to add the generic scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think your previous work in **dev** was mixed with your test work in **testbanch.**

I'm not sure how much test work you have done in **testbranch**. If you haven't done a lot of work, you could:

First pick the commit tag in testbranch through git log.

```
git checkout testbranch
git diff "tag" > /location/out/of/repo
```

Edit /location/out/of/repo, delete the work you have done for test.

```
git checkout dev
git apply /location/out/of/repo
```

Comment: @mu無 yeah, You are right. He should first pick the commit tag.